# Filter fullcalendar events using a select

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a fullcalendar plugin to store doctor's appointments I want at the beginning to show all appointments, but I want the consulting room asistant can filter beetween doctors to display only its corresponding appointments using an html `select`

```
<label for="">Filter by doctor:</label>
<select class="form-control col-4 mb-4" name="select_doctor" id="select_doctor">
  <option value="1">Doctor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Doctor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Doctor 3</option>
</select>
```

this is the callendar definition

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
  titleFormat:{
    hour12: true
  },
  locale: 'es',
  bootstrapFontAwesome: false,
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  },
  eventTimeFormat: {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: true
  },
  events:"{{ url('/agenda/show/') }}"
});
calendar.render();
```

this is the ajax call where is supposed to get the filtered data

```
$('#select_doctor').change(function(){
  var id_doctor = $('#select_doctor').val();

  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"{{url('/agenda/show/')}}"+'/'+id_doctor,
    success:function(response){
  
    },
    error: function (err) {

    }
  });
});
```

this is the route

```
Route::get('/agenda/show/{id?}', 'AppointmentController@show')->name('appointment-show');
```

this is the controller function

```
public function show($id){
  if($id != "null"){

    $data['calendar_doctors']=CalendarDoctor::where('doctor_id', $id)->get();

  }else{

    if(Auth::user()->hasRole('doctor')){

      $data['calendar_doctors']=CalendarDoctor::where('doctor_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    
    }else{
    
      $data['calendar_doctors']=CalendarDoctor::all();
    
    }

  }
        
  return response()->json($data['calendar_doctors']);
}
```

I don't know if this is the best option or there is some sort of client-side filtering or an easy way to filter

Comment: It's not clear, are you saying there's a problem with this code, or are you asking if there's any other way to achieve it?

Comment: @ADyson no problem with the code above, I just don't know how to complete the `$.ajax` success to render the events filtered

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the simplest way to structure your client-side code.

As per fullCalendar's [events as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) documentation, you can configure the event feed so that you can run a custom AJAX request, so it's easy to structure the URL the way you need it. This can be done whenever a request for events is made.

e.g. in your case:

```
events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
  var id_doctor = $('#select_doctor').val();

  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"{{url('/agenda/show/')}}"+ (id_doctor != "" ? '/' + id_doctor : ""),
  }).done(function(data) {
    successCallback(data); //use the supplied callback function to return the event data to fullCalendar
  }).fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    failureCallback(jqXHR);
  });
}
```

Then the "change" event handler for your select simply needs to tell the calendar to [refresh the events from the server](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents):

```
$('#select_doctor').change(function() {
  calendar.refetchEvents();
});
```

You also need to amend your HTML select so there's an "all" option, so that this can be the initial default, and so the user can toggle back to it if they want to:

```
<label for="">Filter by doctor:</label>
<select class="form-control col-4 mb-4" name="select_doctor" id="select_doctor">
  <option value="">-- All --</option>
  <option value="1">Doctor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Doctor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Doctor 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
           eventSources: [

                // your event source
                {
                url: '{{ url("/agenda/show/") }}',
                method: 'GET',
                extraParams: {
                    select_doctor: $('#select_doctor').val(),
                    custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
                },
                failure: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                //color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                //textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
                }

                // any other sources...

            ],
```